# Display more recent and less recent posts in same category

Tags: functions

Is there a way to display not just the-most-recent posts in a category, but the 3 posts in a category more recent (time-wise) than the current post?

For example, Jan10post Jan15post Jan17post | Jan22post (currently viewing) | Jan23post Jan30post Feb2post

I have the following code as a starting point, but how to tell WordPress to start at the current post, find the child-most category of the post, and display less/more recent posts I haven't found anywhere.

```
function my_custom_loop_2 ($category, $tag, $offset) {
        $args=array(
          // showposts has been replaced, use 'posts_per_page' instead
          // 'showposts'        =>1,
          'posts_per_page'      => 3,
          // this has been replaced, use 'ignore_sticky_posts'
          // 'caller_get_posts' => 1,
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        );

        if ($category) {
          $args['cat'] = $category;
        }

        if ($tag) {
          $args['tag'] = $tag;
        }

        if ($offset) {
          $args['offset'] = $offset;
        }

        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        // ... rest of function to output loop 

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
             <div class="three-titles">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></br>
             </div>
            <?php
            endwhile;
        } //if ($my_query)

        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
```

};
and

```
<?php my_custom_loop_3(13, NULL, 1); ?>
```

Comment: I can't think of a way to do what you want with a single query _(as far as I know there's currently no negative offset support)_ and I wouldn't recommend using multiple queries for such a small feature. You might consider taking the date of current post, calculate date 3-5 days back, also 3-5 days forward and get posts `BETWEEN` that timeframe. **Also** Calling `wp_reset_query()` is not necessary after using `WP_Query()` as it doesn't modify the main query object. Instead use `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it's kind of outside current WordPress code ability. If it can't be done, I'll just give up on it.

Comment: Im sure there's a way _(like always)_ but it will probably require some custom SQL code _(because that's also what all WordPress database actions/functions are, just SQL already written for you and working in background)_. You might be better off asking this in stackoverflow.com because I haven't studied SQL yet.

Comment: Yeah, that's beyond what I can do. I've only learned WordPress php. In this case, the achievement would be less than what it would take to get it. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Are you trying to display the 3 posts before the rest of your list of posts or ordered with your other posts? In essence, should this be separate or together?

Comment: HI MikeNGarrett, I don't really understand that question. Sorry. I'll try to give an example: so you're on a post published 1 month ago in category=Salmon. It would have that post, then below I'd like to show (like we do with most-recent posts and related posts) the three more recent posts (3 posts published in "Salmon" after current post was published), then the current post (the same one we're already reading), then the thee less recent (3 posts published in "Salmon" previous to the current post.

Answer (score 1):

### The challenge:

Get n = quantity older and newer posts from the recent posts with the same categories and/or tags.

### The solution:

Like @TwerkingN00b suggested, we do need some custom SQL here. The magic SQL phrase we are looking for is [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

All the other stuff is knowledge how WordPress handles SQL queries, how to get the relevant data and then putting it all together. Let us start:

Setting up the basics. Our reference post (= current ID if nothing is supported), its date and some empty variables additionally we want to direct our query to ignore or accept the associated categories or terms.

```
function the_assoc_posts($post_id = 0, $quantity = 3, $ignore_categories = false, $ignore_tags = false) {
    if (empty($post_id)) $post_id = get_the_ID();
    if (empty($post_id)) return;

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $date = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_id );
    $cat = array();
    $tag = array();
```

Now we need to get all the categories of our post.

```
    if (!$ignore_categories) {
        $post_categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'category' );
        if (!empty($post_categories) && is_array($post_categories)) {
            foreach ($post_categories as $category) {
                $cat[] =  $category->term_id;
            }
            $cat = implode(',',$cat);
        }
    }
```

Now we need to get all the post_tags of our post.

```
    if (!$ignore_tags) {
        $post_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id );
        if (!empty($post_tags) && is_array($post_tags)) {
            foreach ($post_tags as $post_tag) {
                $tag[] =  $post_tag->term_id;
            }
            $tag = implode(',', $tag);
        }
    }
```

Because Wordpress doesn't supports this kind of queries (yet) we have to rebuild the basic query and adapt it to our needs.

```
    global $wpdb, $post;

    $innerjoin = array();
    $where = array();

    if (!empty($cat)) {
        $innerjoin[]= "INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tt1 ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = tt1.object_id)";
        $where[] = "tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN ($cat)";
    }
    if (!empty($tag)) {
        $innerjoin[]= "INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tt2 ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = tt2.object_id)";
        $where[] = "tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN ($tag)";
    }
    $innerjoin = implode("\n", $innerjoin);
    if (!empty($where))
        $where = 'WHERE ('.implode(" AND \n", $where).') AND';
    else
        $where = "WHERE";

    $query = "SELECT
      $wpdb->posts.ID,
      $wpdb->posts.post_date as DateOrder,
      2 SortOrder
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    {$innerjoin}
    {$where} $wpdb->posts.ID = {$post_id}
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT
      $wpdb->posts.ID,
      $wpdb->posts.post_date,
      3
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    {$innerjoin}
    {$where}
    $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date > '{$date}'
    GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date ASC LIMIT $quantity)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT
      $wpdb->posts.ID,
      $wpdb->posts.post_date,
      1
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    {$innerjoin}
    {$where} $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < '{$date}'
    GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC LIMIT $quantity)
    ORDER BY SortOrder ASC, DateOrder DESC";
```

I found the basics on how to get rows before and after a particular row on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836279/mysql-select-before-after-row) and the sorting was also explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766359/does-union-all-guarantee-the-order-of-the-result-set). To find out how the current version of WordPress (v4.4) handles the query I built a custom query with [tax_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) parameters and echoed the SQL.

Now we need to loop through the found posts.

```
    $loop = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    if ( $loop ) {
        foreach ( $loop as $row ) {
            $post = get_post($row->ID);
            setup_postdata( $post );
            ?>
            <div class="three-titles">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"<?php echo (get_the_ID() == $post_id?' class="current"':'')?>><?php the_title(); ?></a></br>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

And we got results. To get the associated posts:

- Inside the loop: `the_assoc_posts();`
- Outside the loop: `the_assoc_posts($post_id);`
- With max. of 5 associated posts: `the_assoc_posts($post_id, 5);`
- Ignore associated categories: `the_assoc_posts(null, 3, false);`
- Ignore associated tags: `the_assoc_posts(null, 3, true, false);`